# Maven - staging deployment

Tags: java, maven, svn

I have a java project that is managed with maven.
When I commit the project into SVN it contains the pom files that are used by a central build/deployment engine.

I want to set up maven to deploy the war into my staging server (tomcat).
I don't have problem with the task itself.
My problem is that I cannot commit into the SVN information about the staging deployment procedure.
I would like to have a local pom file, extending the parent pom and doing an extra task (tha staging deployment); this could solve my problem because I could simply exclude this pom from SVN commit.

Is there any way to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating an extra aggregator for your local use. This aggregator will have your current aggregator (or your modules if you dont use aggregator) and the task to deploy. At your local computer, you should use this aggregator to build and install your project when ever you want to deploy the war.